# Update jface table when model nested field changed

Tags: java, eclipse, data-binding, jface, observable

I have small Job and JobManager domain classes:

```
public class Job extends ModelObject {
    private String name;
    private String state;
    public State getState() {return state;}
    public void setState(final State state) {this.state = state;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
}

public class JobManager extends ModelObject {
    private List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    public List<Job> getJobs() {
    return jobs;
    }
    public void addJob(Job job) {
        jobs.add(job);
        firePropertyChange("jobs", null, null);
    }
    public void removeJob(Job job) {
    jobs.remove(job);
    firePropertyChange("jobs", null, null);
    }
}
```

Then I use JFace databinding to update TableViewer.

```
... // TableViewer tableViewer;
... // JobManager jobManager;
IObservableList jobs = BeanProperties.list(JobManager.class, "jobs").observe(jobManager);
tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ObservableListContentProvider());
... // set label provider etc
tableViewer.setInput(jobs);
```

This works fine.
When I add job to job manager - jobManager.add(job) the new line appears in the table view.
When I remove job from job manager - jobManager.remove(job) the corresponding line removes from the table view.

But also I want update table view when job state changed for example from "state1" to "state2" - job.setState("state2");
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be helpful to someone.
To realize such behavior just override equals and hashCode in Job class and call
firePropertyChange("state", null, null) in Job.setState().

```
public void setState(final State state) {
    this.state = state;
    firePropertyChange("state", null, null);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Job))
        return false;
    final Job other = (Job) o;
    return name.equals(other.name)
        && state == other.state;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + state.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```